# django cross site redirection crsf token security

Tags: python, django

Ive been trying to integrate a payment method for my website, it requires verification from an external webpage (bank), it requires a response_url, from which the status and dat wil be posted back on my site, when it operates django gives me an error requiring a csrf token for posting a form, I found a workaround setting @csrf_exempt, but I asume its not the optimal solution, since is less secure, what is the correct solution for csrf token solicitaiton when posting from an external page?

```
def pay_started(request):
usu = CuentaUsusario.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
response_url = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8000/cuentas/pay_inscr_finish/'

if request.method == 'POST':
    
        username = request.POST.get('user_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        response_url = request.POST.get('response_url')
        req = request.POST

        resp = MallInscription.start(user_name=username,email=email,response_url=response_url)

        return render(request,'c_cuentas/pay_started.html',{'usu':usu,'resp':resp,'req':req})

    return render(request,'c_cuentas/pay_started.html',{'usu':usu,'response_url':response_url})


@csrf_exempt
def pay_inscr_finish(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
   
    req = request.POST
    token = request.POST.get('TBK_TOKEN')
    resp = MallInscription.finish(token=token)

    ttoken = resp.transbank_user
    authoriz_code = resp.authorization_code
    tarjeta = resp.card_type
    ult_dig = resp.card_number

    return render(request,'c_cuentas/pay_inscr_finish.html',{
                    'utl_digit':utl_digit,
                    'tarjeta':tarjeta,
                    'ttoken':ttoken,
                    'authoriz_code':authoriz_code})
```

Comment: `@csrf_exempt` is the correct answer in this case ... typically before redirecting you can store some random state variable and pass it to the external site, and verify on response that it matches your expected state variable... but csrf is really only for requests originating from your site (or at a minimum where you have complete control over the request)